# Append a tuple to a list

Tags: python

Given a tuple (specifically, a functions varargs), I want to prepend a list containing one or more items, then call another function with the result as a list. So far, the best I've come up with is:

```
def fn(*args):
    l = ['foo', 'bar']
    l.extend(args)
    fn2(l)
```

Which, given Pythons usual terseness when it comes to this sort of thing, seems like it takes 2 more lines than it should. Is there a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can convert the tuple to a list, which will allow you to concatenate it to the other list.  ie:

```
def fn(*args):
    fn2(['foo', 'bar'] + list(args))
```

Comment: Something exactly like that. Oh the shame.

Answer (score 1):

If your fn2 took varargs also, you wouldn't need to build the combined list:

```
def fn2(*l):
    print l

def fn(*args):
    fn2(1, 2, *args)

fn(10, 9, 8)
```

produces

```
(1, 2, 10, 9, 8)
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately fn2 is a third party API and doesn't take varargs.